# Magmi Value Replacer news_from_date

Tags: php, magmi

looking for a little bit of assistance for using magmi to create the column news_from_date.

I try to use the Value Replacer tool to create the column news_from_date. The value that I use is `{{date(Y-m-d)}}`.

However when running the import script, the wrong format of date is created (as I can see because in the backend shows the new from date as 30-11-00-1.

What is incorrect in my syntax?

Already tried `{{date(Y/m/d)}}` but also doesn\’t seem to work.

Thank you for you help.

Regards,

Oebel

Comment: what version of magmi are you using ?

Comment: Hi Dweeves, Axel answered my question with the solution provided below. It works excellent. Thanks for your excellent tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the MySQL date syntax

```
{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}
```

This is what I use in Magmi and it works.

Also, don't forget the single quotes `'` in the date() function.